# Using multiline with std::tr1::regex

Tags: c++, regex, replace, comments, multiline

I have an awesome regex that strips c/c++ style comments.

```
std::tr1::regex rx1( "//.*?$|/\\*.*?\\*/|\\'(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\\\'])*\\'|\"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\\"])*" );
str = std::regex_replace( str, rx1, std::string("") );
```

The only problem is that it matches only on one line. How can I use std::tr1::regex to match on all lines?